# ngrok command not found

Tags: macos, localhost, tunnel, ngrok

I'm trying to install `ngrok` (which I've been using for a while on Windows with no issues) on my 1 week old yosemite and these are the steps I've followed so far.

1. Downloaded ngrok from here https://ngrok.com/download.
2. Unziped the file and copied the Unix Executable File into
   application.

Now from what I understand I just need to open the terminal, move inside the application folder and write `ngrok http 80`. The result of this is "command not found".

I've even signed up at the `ngrok` website and run from terminal the command `./ngrok authtoken "blablabla"` and the result is "No such file or directory"

Can anyone tell me how to proceed to be able to activate the tunnel with `ngrok`?

Comment: Start by making sure you're in the right directory.  `ls ngrok` should show you that the file exists.  After that, `./ngrok <whatever options>` should work or at least invoke the right program.

Comment: Thank you Phillip.. I took for granted that I was in /Application but I wasn't.. I was trying to lunch ngrok from users/USERNAME/applications.
To go into the right folder I've just written from terminal "cd /Applications" instead of "cd Application". I guess those are newbie errors.  Thank you very much

Comment: A Mac trick is: type "cd " in a terminal window and then drag the folder for the directory you want to be in from Finder to Terminal.  What you drag changes from an icon to a text string.

Comment: Nice trick.. It work as well with the command "ls" if you need to see the content of a folder into the terminal.  Thanks Phillip ;)

Comment: Why not use https://pinggy.io ? Does the same thing without the need to download anything.

Answer (score 336):

**Short answer**: Put the executable file in `/usr/local/bin` instead of applications. You should now be able to run commands like `ngrok http 80`.

**Long answer**: When you type commands like `ngrok` in the terminal, Macs (and other Unix OSs) look for these programs in the folders specified in your `PATH`. The `PATH` is a list of folders that's specified by each user. To check your path, open the terminal and type: `echo $PATH`.

You'll see output that looks something like: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`. This is a `:` separated list of folders.

So when you type `ngrok` in the terminal, your Mac will look for this executable in the following folders: `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin/` and `/bin`.

Read [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux) if you are interested in learning about why you should prefer `usr/local/bin` over other folders.

Comment: `mv ngrok /usr/local/bin`

Comment: If it don't work for you, try the Vick Swigt solution two response bellow.

Comment: in newer versions of macOS you won't find it easy to move or copy binaries to /usr/bin creating an alias or using something like brew to install might be a better option

Comment: where should i be able to find this usr folder

Answer (score 111):

With Homebrew already installed on your Mac, you can easily install ngrok from the terminal, using this command:

```
$ brew install --cask ngrok
```

Then run it from the shell using this command:

```
$ ngrok http 8000
```

With this command, you're telling ngrok to basically create a tunnel to your localhost 8000 and assign an internet name host for it.
And thats it. You should be good to go.

Comment: `brew cask install ngrok` was throwing `Error: Unknown command: cask` for me. Turns out the install command has been updated to: `brew install --cask ngrok`.

Comment: `brew install ngrok/ngrok/ngrok` (per instructions at https://ngrok.com/download) is what worked for me on Apple Silicon; unzipping the download available in the ngrok dashboard (either via finder or terminal) did not work for me.

Comment: Successfully Worked on  mac with apple silicon chip ```brew install ngrok/ngrok/ngrok```

Comment: brew install ngrok --cask

Answer (score 85):

- Download the zip file.
- Unzip it.
- Open The terminal in the current location (inside unzip folder) where you unzip the file.
- Execute the following command into the terminal :

  ```
  sudo cp ngrok /usr/local/bin
  ```

  *Now your **ngrok** execuatable file is successfully copied to the **/usr/local/bin** directory. Now you are able to run the **ngrok** command in the terminal*

Comment: This worked on my ubuntu 18.04 after I have downloaded the ngrok zip.

Comment: This worked on Mac too.

Comment: use sudo has finally worked for me on mac (Monterey 12.0.1). I can't understand, why the extra step with the copy to `usr/local/bin` is not mentioned in the install manual of ngrok. Instead they say "ngrok is easy to install. " Yeah it's easy, but only if you know how.

Comment: This is the straight forward way to go.
 Ngrok should add this to their documentation

Answer (score 33):

**I have also faced this issue on my MacOS, I used these simple steps and it worked for me.**

Just open the terminal and go to your project folder where you what to start ngrok and then unzip downloaded file.

```
$ unzip /path/to/ngrok.zip
```

After doing this you don't need to authenticate ngrok, just run this command:

```
./ngrok  http 80
```

It should work now.

Comment: The only thing that actually worked for me was this. Hero!

Answer (score 28):

This is how I got it to work..

**For Mac**

1. If you downloaded via a download link, you need to add ngrok path to your .bash_profile or .bashrc whichever one you are using.

**For Windows 10 bash:**

1. Download ngrok from https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-windows-amd64.zip
2. Move executable file ngrok.exe to C:\Windows\system32\ngrok.exe
3. Add Environment Variables via UI (search for "Edit the environment variables for your account" in the search bar next to windows logo => double click on Path under Users Variables for yourusername => Click New => add your path C:\Windows\system32\ngrok.exe => click OK.
4. Restart your bash and you should be able to run "ngrok http 80" command.

Comment: Can you show an example of what it looks like for Mac?

Comment: Type "echo $PATH" in your terminal and see what paths comes back.( '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:...etc'). If you installed your package locally, chances are it's in user/local/bin or user/bin, so try to see if ngrok is listed there, if so and your $PATH doesn't have those paths listed, modify $PATH in .bash_profile to include them. https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/ hope it makes sense.. Mine is in My-MacBook-Pro/usr/local/bin/ngrok https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-usr-bin-and-usr-local-bin

Comment: Worked for me on windows, thank you

Comment: Windows solution worked for me. than you for the instructions

Answer (score 24):

I had followed the instructions as per the [ngrok download instructions](https://ngrok.com/download):

[image]

So the file downloaded to ~/Downloads

But I still needed to move ngrok into my binaries folder, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38435256/5783745):

```
mv ~/Downloads/ngrok /usr/local/bin
```

Then running `ngrok` in terminal works

Answer (score 14):

just download it , unzip it run

```
./ngrok http 80
```

Comment: This creates a problem if you are using source control, its unlikely you want to commit a copy of ngrok. The answer moving the executable to `/usr/local/bin` is more sustainable in my view.

Answer (score 6):

For **Linux**  :https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

For **Mac**    :https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-darwin-amd64.zip

For **Windows**:https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-windows-amd64.zip

unzip it 
for linux and mac users move file to `/usr/local/bin` and execute `ngrok http 80` command in the terminal

I don't have any idea about windows

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 10, for me

```sh
ngrok http 80
```

Behaves like this:

- **works from Command Prompt (cmd.exe)**
- *does not work from Git Bash*
- *does not work from Windows PowerShell*

To make available in git bash, you can add the following function to your `.bashrc` file

```sh
function ngrok { cmd.exe /c "ngrok $1 $2 $3";}
```

Answer (score 5):

run sudo npm install ngrok --g
a very simple way to install

sudo because you are installing it globally

Comment: Note that this command might not reflect the most recent version of ngrok.

Answer (score 3):

add line in .zshrc

```
# vi .zshrc

alias ngrok="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/ngrok/bin/ngrok"
```

Answer (score 2):

**For installation in Windows :** [Download](https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-windows-amd64.zip) and extract to any directory (lets say c drive)

- Then double click on the extracted `ngrok.exe` file and you'll be able to see the `command prompt`.
- And just type **ngrok http 4040**  // here I am exposing [port 4040]

Answer (score 1):

On Windows **ngrok.cmd** works well from Git Bash, not ngrok

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked for me was

```
yarn global add ngrok 
yarn global add exp
```

with **npm** I was getting permission errors etc..

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I kept ignoring the instructions that very explicitly tell you to use a terminal on Mac OS, because it *looked* like it was unzipping correctly:

> On Linux or Mac OS X you can unzip ngrok from a terminal with the following command. On Windows, just double click ngrok.zip to extract it.

```
unzip /path/to/ngrok.zip
```

However, as soon as I tried running the above command in my terminal, it worked perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

1. Extract.
2. Open folder
3. Right click Windows Powershell.
4. ngrock http 5000 {your post number instead of 5000}
5. Make sure local server is running on another cmd too.

//Do not worry about auth step

Answer (score 0):

Ngrok  can be installed with Yarn , then you  can  run by power Sheel. it's was the only way that worked for me in windows 10 . In the begin you need to install   the Node : https://nodejs.org/en/. and the yarn: https://nodejs.org/en/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Snap](https://snapcraft.io) for downloading `ngrok`. Follow the steps below:

1. Install `Snap` by following command:

   ```sh
   sudo apt install snapd
   ```
2. Install `Ngrok` by following command:

   ```sh
   sudo snap install ngrok
   ```
3. Now use `ngrok` command from any directory, like this:

   ```sh
   ngrok http 8080
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this with git bash, after install, I was able go to get it to work by adding the path to the exe to my .bashrc file like:

`$ export PATH=$PATH:"/c/<path to containing folder>/ngrok"`

After saving and opening a new shell, running 'ngrok --help' was successful

Answer (score -1):

In shorts,ngrok should be in same directory in which you are running ngrok command.