# Moved ngrok executable to /usr/local/bin but when I run './ngrok http 8000' it returns 'zsh: no such file or directory: ./ngrok'

Tags: django, localhost, ngrok

Not familiar with ngrok, I am reading a book on Django and am trying to set it up. Another question on here ([ngrok command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188582/ngrok-command-not-found)) said to put the executable in `usr/local/bin`. I put it here but when I run `./ngrok http 8000` it returns `zsh: no such file or directory: ./ngrok`

Somethings I can add, I am using a virtual environment and `echo $PATH` returns the following: `/Users/justin/Desktop/djangoByExample/sm/env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

The only thing I am thinking is that because I am in a virtual environment it is not looking at `/usr/local/bin` on my machine and that I need to put this ngrok executable somewhere else related to my virtualenv?

Not sure if I provided enough info, please let me know if anything is missing and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some unix 101:

- A single dot ('.') refers to the current directory.
- A double dot ('..') refers to the parent directory.

As a result, executing `./ngrok` will look for ngrok in the current directory. If you moved it to `/usr/local/bin` but you are in `/Users/justin`, it will still look for `/Users/justin/ngrok`.

We can execute programs in any directory mentioned in $PATH, by not using a directory reference, but just the program name:

`ngrok`

That's it.